# PL/pgSQL return query null type is not returned

Tags: postgresql, null

I in a PL/pgSQL function i have the following statement:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT pd.* FROM  "PushDevice" pd
        WHERE pd."PushNotificationId" =$4 and pd."sentAt" is null;
```

the PushDevice table now has a column called sentAt. If that is null, then i get a returned query that looks like this:

(a,b,c,,d).

The sentAt is not null but it looks like an empty string (not even added). Can i get the returned query to return NULL instead of nothing when the value of the column is null? This is very important as my underlying structure in NHibernate expects something as opposed to an empty field.

I have looked around and the closest thing i had to an answer was using coalesce but that didnt work as string + null = string. null + null = null.

EDIT:

To reiterate my question. My query is correct and the results returned for my query are correct as well. Nevertheless, if a column called sentAt of type timestamp for table PushDevice is null, then postgres doesnt return NULL but instead returns an empty field.

Where a,b,c,d,e are fields and d is sentAt field i would get (a,b,c,,e). d would be omitted by postgres and i need to get it to return null for when the field is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the terms "NULL", "empty string" and "nothing" freely. You need to be very clear here.

And this is wrong: <strike>`string + null = string`</strike>
NULL added or concatenated to anything is *always* NULL.

As for the type `timestamp`, as you clarified: this cannot be an "empty string". Only character data can be empty strings (`''`). What you see (nothing), it the text representation NULL in your client. The data type `timestamp` can only hold valid value or `NULL`. (There are special input values like [`infinity` or `-infinity` or `allballs`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE) (sic!).

If you want to display NULL values as a different string, you need to convert the `timestamp` to `text` (or similar), and change the `RETURN` type of the function accordingly.

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT  a, b, c, COALESCE("sentAt"::text, '<NULL>') AS "sentAt"
FROM   "PushDevice"
WHERE  "PushNotificationId" = $4
AND    "sentAt" IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hey, the database has no value for SentAt. IT is not an empty strung it is literarly null. I need that to show as null as opposed to an empty string that pgsql inteprets it as.

Comment: @Martino: Postgres ***never*** interprets a NULL as empty string. Postgres is about the strictest instance in the world about that you will find.

Comment: My query is 100% correct. The results i get back from my return type of SETOF PushDevice is a list of : (a,b,c,,e). Instead of returning me back a NULL for value of d, it returns nothing, a blank value. This is my problem. Apologies if this was not clear to begin with. Edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: can you provide an example of the return type of the function if i were to return null for the timestamp ignoring other columns or adding dummy stuff for them?

Comment: @Martino: That's backwards. *You* should be providing your function header in the question to begin with. `NULL` is not a type but a value. To return the string `'<NULL>'`, which is not `NULL` instead, the data type would need to be `text` (or similar) instead of `timestamp`, but you probably don't need that. [You need to start with the basics.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

What is empty field?

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE f1(a int, b int, c int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# INSERT INTO f1 VALUES(10,NULL, 20);
INSERT 0 1

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fx_f1()
 RETURNS SETOF f1
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM f1;
  RETURN;
END;
$function$

postgres=# select fx_f1();
  fx_f1   
----------
 (10,,20)
(1 row)

postgres=# select (fx_f1()).b IS NULL;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# \pset null <NULL>
Null display is "<NULL>".

-- it doesn't work as expected, result is record, not table
postgres=# select fx_f1();
  fx_f1   
----------
 (10,,20)
(1 row)

-- fx is correct
postgres=# select * from fx_f1();
 a  |   b    | c  
----+--------+----
 10 | <NULL> | 20
(1 row)
```

Your issue can be problem of your client. Try to use SELECT FROM instead SELECT.